# Get data directly from nested array in AngulaJS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I have problem with reading data from nested array. Previously, I asked how to read data from nested array to display them in a table (as a new row) on HTML page; now, I need display data from nested array directly.

The array's structure: `array1[var1,var2,array2[var3,var4]]`

So... there is my problem:

```
<tr><br>
<td ng-repeat="...">...</td><br>
<tr>
```

I want to read `var3` datas from `array2` "directly", to display them side by side in the table. I need something as this:

```
<tr>
   <td ng-repeat="item in array1.array2">{{item.var3}}</td>
</tr>
```

It is possible?

Comment: yes its possible. Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SC9kDAS2SbO2R3qlbo90?p=preview) code for that.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work. :(

Comment: can you create a plnkr and tell me what you want exactly

Comment: Sorry, the linked code works! There was another problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know the name of the nested array and you are sure it exists, `< tr >< td ng-repeat="item in array1.array2">{{item}}< /td >< /tr >` can work perfectly.

If what you want is to flatten this array from `array1[var1,var2,array2[var3,var4]]` to `[var1, var2, var3, var4]`, [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) can do you a favor